# PingFederate SLO - Status Message: Invalid signature

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, pingfederate

After I invoke single-log-out (SLO), by calling 'GET' on https://[PingFederate Server Instance]:[Port]/sp/startSLO.ping, my PingFederate server begins making requests to my SP logout services. [I know this because I can see it happening in Fiddler.]

But when one my SPs invokes `“https://<PingFederate DNS>:XXXX” + request.getParameter(“resume”);` (per @Scott T.'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8262768/109941)), I get an error message:

> Error - Single Logout Nonsuccess Response status:
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester Status Message: Invalid
>   signature Your Single Logout request did not complete successfully. To
>   logout out of your Identity Provider and each Service Provider, close
>   all your browser windows.    Partner: XXXX:IDP    Target Resource:
>   `http://<domain>/<default SLO endpoint>`

My Questions:

- What is this error message referring to?
- How can I resolve this error condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is likely due to a mismatch in configuration between IdP and SP.  The signing keys/certificate for SAML messages used at one end, must match the verification certificate at the other end.  Check your Credentials configuration on your connection for both IdP and SP.  See [this section](https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-92&topicId=adminGuide%2FconfiguringCredentials.html) in the PingFederate Administration Guide for some details.